# MySQL Server Install Setup Types Developer Default vs Full

Tags: mysql

As I'm installing MySQL Server Community Edition the possible Setup Types are:

- Developer Default
- Server Only
- Client Only
- Full
- Custom

Is there **any difference** between options **Developer Default** and **Full**? As I get to the lists of products to be installed (MySQL Server, MySQL Workbench, Connectors etc.) they seem identical.

Comment: The difference is probably in configuration, i.e. which default configuration (my-medium, my-large, my-huge...) is copied to my.cnf.

Comment: Later in the setup there's the selection of Server configuration type: Development machine - Server machine - Dedicated machine that probably changes that config. It still might have something to do with it so thanks for the suggestion.